# EXCEL SUMIFS with dynamic tabs (INDIRECT)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to get below `SUMIFS` formula to work with `INDIRECT`. I have data for each week in separate tabs .. ie WEEK05, WEEK06 etc. The result of the formula (a date) will come from column W based on criterias met from column B with the value in cell A1 and criterias met from column F with the value in cell B1

```
=SUMIFS(WEEK05!W9:W25;WEEK05!B9:B25;A1;WEEK05!F9:F25;B1)
```

I want to insert the week in cell C1 so that `SUMIFS` will use that string, for example:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(C1&"!W9:W25;INDIRECT(C1&"!B9:B25;A1;INDIRECT(C1&"!F9:F25;B1))))
```

... where C1 is currently equal to `WEEK05`, `WEEK06` etc.

[Function Arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9mvJ.jpg)

Comment: Where are you trying to use `INDIRECT`?

Comment: I try to use it like this

=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(C1&"!W9:W25;INDIRECT(C1&"!B9:B25;A1;INDIRECT(C1&"!F9:F25;B1))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, I believe you're missing some quotation marks and incorrectly placing your closing parenthesis in your current formula:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(C1&"!W9:W25");INDIRECT(C1&"!B9:B25");A1;INDIRECT(C1&"!F9:F25");B1)
```

Comment: It works :) :) 

The correct formula actually find data in another excel sheet which I have open

The formula looks like this

=SUMIFS('[Deadlines - L34.xlsx]WEEK05'!P9:P24;'[Deadlines - L34.xlsx]WEEK05'!B9:B24;A1;'[Deadlines - L34.xlsx]WEEK05'!F9:F24;B1)

I have tried to "convert" the answer from you but can't do it right :(

I have tried flw. - can you see what is wrong?

=SUMIFS(INDIRECT('[Deadlines - L34.xlsx]C1&"'!P9:P24);INDIRECT('[Deadlines - L34.xlsx]C1&"!B9:B24");A1;INDIRECT('[Deadlines - L34.xlsx]C1&"!F9:F24";B1))

Comment: @jaybee1967 I think you've got your quotes mixed up again :) You need quotes around all of the *static* parts, in this case, `"[Deadlines - L34.xlsx]"&C1&"!P9:P24"`, as the only dynamic part of this is what you're taking from `C1`. Try this: `=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("[Deadlines - L34.xlsx]"&C1&"!P9:P24");INDIRECT("[Deadlines - L34.xlsx]"&C1&"!B9:B24");A1;INDIRECT("[Deadlines - L34.xlsx]"&C1&"!F9:F24");B1)`

Comment: I get an error #REF! .. I have added an image (link) to the question showing the Function arguments if this can help.